# How to make slide / swiper using JS?

Tags: javascript, slider, slideshow, swiper.js, slide

I am trying to create little slider, made out of 3 cards containing profile picture of customer and some info. After clicking left/right arrow button, new card with new customer should show up after smooth transition to left/right depending on which button was clicked.

[image]
`

```
  <h1>Our Customers</h1>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='swiper'>
      <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
        <div class='swiper-slide'>
          <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595152772835-219674b2a8a6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxfDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080&utm_source=unsplash_source&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=api-credit'/>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad</p>
          <h2>Customer 1</h2>
          <i>profession of customer</i>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='buttons'>
    <button class='prev'>&lt;</button>
    <button class='next'>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

`

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  :root {
    --swiper-theme-color: black;
  }
  
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .card {
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 13px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .swiper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .buttons {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .prev,.next {
    display: inline;
    margin: 12px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background-color: #6F7A9B;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

``Here is photo of what I have and source code. I am struggling to add transitions and card changing using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using swiper.js? If not, I would suggest you to use it. Really helpful tool.